# Can I construct partitions in DolphinDB database with hours?

Tags: partitioning, dolphindb

From DolphinDB tutorial, the optimal size of a partition is around 100MB. For my use case, partitions based on dates are too large. I need to construct partitions based on date + hour. Does anyone know the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a COMPOSITE partition of DATE and HOUR, but a more straightforward way is to use the data type "DATEHOUR".

https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?datehour.html